# DEBUGGER: Attaching after process <pid1> fork to child process <pid2>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, zeus

When using the ruby [debug gem](https://github.com/ruby/debug), I often see the following output printed out:

```
DEBUGGER: Attaching after process <pid1> fork to child process <pid2>
```

where `<pid1>` is a parent process id like 12345 and `<pid2>` is a newly forked child process id, like 55555.

What is going on here? Has it got anything to do with connecting to application preloaders like [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) or [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's coming from this code here:
https://github.com/ruby/debug/blob/4af8c25140a7a672db852954b6a1733b3169b608/lib/debug/session.rb#L2129-L2162

What's happening is that your main Ruby process is forking off a new process, and it's telling you that the debugger is attaching to the newly-created child process with process id `<pid2>`, so that it too can break for debugging events.

In my case, this was happening when calling `visit <url>` in an automated test which, due to having a Capybara Selenium webdriver, creates a new child process to spin up a Chrome process to render the request's HTML.

By default, the ruby [debug gem](https://github.com/ruby/debug) will attach to **both** the parent and child processes. But you can override to only activate the debugger for either the child or parent by using the `RUBY_DEBUG_FORK_MODE` environment variable.

To be clear, it has nothing to do with application preloaders like Spring or Zeus.